# Google Maps API not functioning in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I've been trying to follow a tutorial on the link below, so to utilize the Google maps API within an Android application, but I just can't manage to get it to work properly. I have checked out this website and others. I've requested a new API key several times, I've made sure it was requested correctly (SHA1 fingerprint then my project name, which in this case is "com.example.reallystuck"). I've also made sure the code is correct but still it won't work, I just get the error "*Unfortunately GoogleMaps V2 has stopped*" when loading it up on the android emulator as in the picture below.

If I have got any of the code wrong or done something stupid, I don't mind people pointing it out to me. I just want it to work.

[Tutorial I have used](https://web.archive.org/web/20180120093050/http://umut.tekguc.info:80/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step).

[image: On open app error screenshot]
.

Code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.reallystuck; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions; 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {     
private GoogleMap mMap;         
@Override     
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);             
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();         
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);         
final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);         
Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()                                   
.position(CIU).title("My Office"));     
}     
@Override     
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {         
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.         
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);         
return true;     } }
```

Android Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.reallystuck"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
        <permission
        android:name="com.example.reallystuck.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.example.reallystuck.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="REMOVED KEY"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.reallystuck.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"    
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"    
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"    
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView        
android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"        
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Link to logcat file:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/1z75u6xmz97bz6z/log.txt

Comment: Please post your logcat, it'll show exactly what the problem is.

Comment: link to logcat:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/1z75u6xmz97bz6z/log.txt

Comment: I saw that thread, and attempted that fix. And still doesn't work. So not a duplicate

Comment: You should try to acquaint yourself with [Android's debugging tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html). They will simplify finding the cause of various problems by among other things, providing you with a clear stack of calls from a uncaught exception.

Comment: I've tried and still haven't found out what's wrong. Have you found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is not complete. You should add the following lines into < application > element:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Please refer to [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2)

Comment: When I do that error still occurs (as in screenshot)

Comment: well, the logcat is quite clear about the problem...If you add those lines what error do you get?

Comment: Yes. I can't find anything else in there, that I haven't already done. I get the same error after adding those lines.

Comment: Here is the logcat for after I add that. 

http://www.mediafire.com/view/1h0bbzi95bfpwam/log(2).txt

Comment: well this time you have a null pointer exception. what is the 17th line of the MainActivity class?

Comment: mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

Comment: Maybe the google play services are not available..can you please post the value returned by calling `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)` method?

Comment: I'm not able to call that, that when I attempt it:

Toast.makeText(this, GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

I get the error DemoGoogleMapsV2 has stopped before the toast message.

Comment: Play services are not available on emulator. Try real device

Comment: well your emulator does not have google play services. You should use an emulator with android version 4.2.2 or higher with google APIs, which has those services installed.

Comment: My emulator had version 4.2.2 installed. I've just attempted to run the above program on a version 4.4.2 and the same error occurs.

Comment: Yes, but is the emulator platform the `Google APIs` one?

Comment: Error occurs for both variations. Just tried

Comment: It should also be noted that you should run a null check on map object before trying to set it up. The tutorial you followed is not a very good one